# LSTM initial state for each item in the batch in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) to run an LSTM in tensorflow. I have a tensor of `N` initial state vectors and a tensor of `M = N * n` inputs. Each series consists of `n` input items, and I want to evaluate the i-th set of input vectors with the i-th initial state vector, as shown below:

```
inputs[0:n], initial_states[0]
inputs[n:2*n], initial_states[1]
...
```

Is there a way to do it with a single call `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` and the above tensors directly, or do I have to resort to a loop for each initial state vector and its corresponding inputs (resulting in `len(initial_states)` calls to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`)?

Comment: Isn't this just normal batching? So your initial [initial_state](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) would have a batch dimension over `N`, and the RNN would run for `n` steps on those batches. You just need to reshape `inputs` to be `[N, n]`. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I ... did not know that, thank you. Please provide that response in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding a bit of detail from comments on the question)

This kind of batching is well supported, and is typically necessary to get good performance. Your [initial_state](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) will have a batch dimension over N, and the RNN will run for n steps on those batches. You just need to reshape inputs to be [N, n, ...] (with `time_major=False`, the default).

It gets trickier when you have variable-length inputs which need to be batched together. Something like [SequenceQueueingStateSaver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/SequenceQueueingStateSaver) can help there.